# facebook started requesting that our users all us to "access friend list"

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We require facebook sign-in for all members.  Some of our existing members started experiencing a sign-in problem last night when logging in facebook would request that our site "would like to access your friend list".  Given that friends list is part of the basic info we can't figure out why all of a sudden facebook is requesting this information.  Has anybody else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with Facebook and will be resolved soon. [See this link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/528423520559440?browse=external_tasks_search_results_521472e6174b98716921665) to read more about it.

Also, I asked a similar question on meta - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194086/why-does-stack-exchange-want-to-access-my-facebook-friends-list